# Comparing two files with multiple columns

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, awk, nested

Need to compare first column from File1 with the first column of File2. If matches, then compare second column of the two files. If second column is **not matching** then print the line from File1 and save the output in another file.

files1.txt

```
80002288    b17
97380002001 b18
97380002220 b17
97380002233 b18
80002333    b17
16501111    b04
16505044    b04
16505042    b04
97316505030  b05
16505043    b04
16505048    b04
```

Files2.txt

```
97366630003 a01
97380002288 b17
97380002001 b17
97380002220 b17
97380002233 b17
97380002333 b17
97316501111 b04
97316505044 b04
97316505042 b04
97316505030 b04
97316505043 b04
```

Desired Output

```
97380002001 b17
97316505030 b04
```

Comment: I believe there are only 2 columns in each file, but it's not clear in the question as the contents of the files are in a single line. Please update the question if this is the case.

Comment: You are encouraged to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Your output seems to have the lines from File2, not File1. Besides, the line `97380002233 b18` should be also included in the output, right?

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match the description of problem.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't make sense with respect to your stated requirements and sample input.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1: without any external library

Use the below code to get the output using only python

```
with open('files3.txt', 'w') as files3:
    with open('files1.txt') as files1:
        for line_a in files1.readlines():
            words_a = line_a.split()
            with open('files2.txt') as files2:
                for line_b in files2.readlines():
                    words_b = line_b.split()
                    if words_a[0] == words_b[0] and words_a[1] != words_b[1]:
                        diff_words = ' '.join(words_b)
                        files3.write(diff_words + '\n')
                        print(diff_words)
```

Output of above code

```
97380002001 b17
97380002233 b17
97316505030 b04
```

---

Approach 2: using Pandas library

You can use the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html#getting-started) library of python to achieve this.
So first install pandas library like:

```
pip install pandas
```

Then run below python code to create the desired file

```
import pandas as pd

# you can replace files1.txt and files2.txt with the complete path if files aren't in the same folder
df1 = pd.read_csv("files1.txt", sep=r'\s+', names=['c1', 'c2'])
df2 = pd.read_csv("files2.txt", sep=r'\s+', names=['c1', 'c2'])

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='c1')
df3 = df3[(df3["c2_x"] != (df3["c2_y"]))]

# use below if you want to save values from file 2
print(df3[['c1', 'c2_y']].to_string(index=False, header=False))
df3[['c1', 'c2_y']].to_csv("files3.txt", sep=' ', index=False, header=False)

# use below if you want to save values from file 1
# print(df3[['c1', 'c2_x']].to_string(index=False, header=False))
# df3[['c1', 'c2_x']].to_csv("Files3.txt", sep=' ', index=False, header=False)

# use below code to save values from both files
# print(df3.to_string(index=False, header=False))
# df3.to_csv("Files3.txt", sep=' ', index=False, header=False)
```

Output of above code

```
97380002001 b17
97380002233 b17
97316505030 b04
```

Comment: I tried following but im getting matched item, Not getting not matched value.                    
 **awk 'FNR!=NR {a[$1]++; next} a[$1]' $input2 $input1**

Comment: Im cannot install pip in that server.

Comment: @dev05btech please check the updated Approach 1

Answer (score 0):

Either of these is probably what you want but your posted expected output doesn't match  either interpretation of your requirements. Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

To print the lines from file1:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} ($1 in a) && (a[$1] != $2)' file2 file1
97380002001 b18
97380002233 b18
97316505030  b05
```

To print the lines from file2 just swap the input file names:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} ($1 in a) && (a[$1] != $2)' file1 file2
97380002001 b17
97380002233 b17
97316505030 b04
```